# Submitting forms using AJAX in laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I have created a form  to submit the data into the database. This is working fine when I don't use AJAX.

Even after adding ajax  it takes me to another page and displays the  text, what I have returned in the controller.

My controller function

```
 public function newAppointment(Request $request){
    // Validate the request...
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'mobile' => 'numeric|required',
        'date' => 'date|required',
        'time' => 'required',
    ]);

    $otp = rand(100000, 999999);

    $schedule = new \App\Schedules;

    $schedule->name   = $request->name;
    $schedule->email  = $request->email;
    $schedule->mobile = $request->mobile;
    $schedule->date   = $request->date;
    $schedule->time   = $request->time;

    $schedule->save();

    $id = $schedule->id;

    $verify = array('otp'=>$otp, 'id'=>$id);
    echo json_encode(array('verify'=> $verify));


}
```

Ajax Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function (e){
            $("#newAppointment").on('submit',(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "appointment",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  {name: $("#name").val, email: $("#email").val, mobile: $("#mobile").val, date: $("#date").val, time: $("#time").val },
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert(data.error->first());
                    }           
                });
            }));
        });
        </script>
```

When I click on the Submit button,  I get a some  text as output, i.e. what I have returned in the controller,  in a new page.

How can I be on the same page after submitting the form.

```
{"verify":{"otp":847042,"id":44}}
```

Comment: you still being redirected after submitting the form ? is that your main problem ?

Comment: if i understand your problem correctly you want not redirect after you submit form click. you must change type of you submit button to button Or after Ajax request add return false; statement

Comment: Yes, When i click on submit button I'm being redirected to a blank page with text that I'm returning on my controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  $("#newAppointment").on('click',(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/appointment",
                type: "POST",
                data:  {name: $("#name").val(), email: $("#email").val(), mobile: $("#mobile").val(), date: $("#date").val(), time: $("#time").val() },
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function(msg){
                    console.log(msg)
                }           
            });
        }));
```

Comment: still being redirected to a new page with text that I'm redirecting in my controller..

Comment: ok, try also adding your form code from the form opening to closing to see if theres an issue here, otherwise also try adding `return false;` in the success and error functions to also prevent the form being sent, etc

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to submit the form. Just send the AJAX request (type POST) to the URL (/appointment) that you have defined in ROUTE that takes you to the function newAppointment.

Try to return something in the controller so you can receive it in

```
success: function(data){
    alert("Success");
},
```

in data you should have what you have returned in the controller.

Comment: I am returning an array in json format on success . echo json_encode(array('verify'=> $verify));

Comment: No, _echo_ is printing on the browser. Use _return json_encode(array('verify'=> $verify));_ to send the information back to the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed echo to return, but as I'm returning an array from my controller using syntax return _json_encode(array('verify' => $verify));_. So, how can I print this on my view..

Comment: you are receiving the array in the success function in Javascript (data variable). So, you can echo(data) or use jQuery to put the information whereever you want.

Comment: The problem is when I use _$("#errors").html(data);_, it prints **{"verify":{"otp":183111,"id":5}}**. And _$("#errors").html(data["otp"]);_ is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#newAppointment").submit(function(){
   ...
   ...
});
```

OR

```
$("#newAppointment").on('submit', function(){
   ...
   ...
});
```

Comment: Tried both but still I'm getting redirected to a new page with text that I've encoded in json format..

Answer (score 0):

because your js code has an error:

```
error: function(data){
    alert(data.error->first());
}
```

this will cause this event never occurs.

Comment: I tried like this.error: function(data){
       alert(data.error.first);
      }  Now I'm getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218 error..